Movie about a little blonde girl who was runs from woman through the woods then falls off from a cliff and dies
I watched this movie years ago, I am not sure if it was a big film for the movies or a Television movie (probably this one since it seems VERY hard to find...), I am also not sure about how old the movie is but I think is was from the 90's or early 2000, I watched it only once on Television some years ago but I never knew the title.
"It's about 2 blonde girls with their family, before the younger girl goes missing  the older sister was jealous of the attention her sister was getting and wished she was not there anymore (later on she tells her parents she thinks its her fault she disappeared because she wished for this).
I remember also that the younger sister before she went missing was at the mall with a woman who was deaf, she was helping her, when she was about to leave she saw someone she knew, a man I don't remember well but I think he was fat and drove a red car but I'm not very sure, she goes with him and then he takes her to the forest covering her eyes with a handkerchief or something,  telling her that her family made a surprise party there so she has to be quiet so when they are out of the car she starts getting suspicious and takes off the handkerchief realizing there is no party so she  starts running away scared and ends up falling off a cliff and dies because of it, I remember she was wearing a red dress, I also remember the mother was so desperate that she ripped off a bible thinking how can God not help her to find her daughter or something like that just out of desperation",
The deaf woman that was with the girl helped the police saying that she went with a man and that she said something when she saw him but she didn't know what was it because she is deaf, I also remember the police going to the family's house and telling them they found their little girl but dead.
Could anyone let me know what this movie is?
